# Можно ли как-то сделать, что-бы не прописывать для каждого значения переменной $x отдельный участок кода, присваивающий значение переменной $b?

Tags: php

```
<?php
switch ($x) {
case 0: $b=a;
...
case 25: $b=z;
...
case 26: $b=aa;
};
?>
```

Мне нужно много переменных, количество которых может быть любым. Что-бы для каждого значения было определено значение переменной $b. Как это реализовать? Значение $x это число.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php. RTFM ;)

Comment: Даниил, если вам подошел какой-либо из ответов на ваш вопрос, не забывайте отмечать его как верный ;) Это и простимулирует отвечать на ваши вопросы и далее, и поможет другим пользователям в последующем соориентироваться в той же проблеме, что и у вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас второй за час вопрос из разряда "первый класс программирования", осторожнее, скоро вас в принудительном порядке начнут отправлять изучать документацию. По сути вопроса: используйте массив. Сначала определите все необходимые вам значения:

```
x[0]=a;
...
x[25]=z;
...
x[26]=aa;
```

а потом используйте их в коде, обращаясь к нужному элементу так: `echo x[0];`, например. Есть еще более короткая форма записи приведенного выше кода (спасибо можно сказать пользователю E_p).

```
$x = [0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3 => "d"];
```

Comment: Ну и раз уж поучаете - возьмите строки в кавычки.

Comment: @u_mulder не знаю, где вы увидели поучение, но вообще я просто предпочел оставить так, как было у автора - кто его знает, что он тут имел ввиду, константы, строки, переменные, которым забыл спереди подставить $.

Comment: `x[0]="a"; x[1]="b"; ...` =>  `$x = ["a", "b", "c", "d" ...]` || `$x = [0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3 => "d" ...]`?

Comment: @E_p Да, последний вариант, думаю, лучше всего подойдет автору вопроса, вынесу его в ответ.